# How to work around Eclipse refactoring ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

Eclipse EE 2022-06 is broken for day-to-day refactoring; it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` for simple class renaming or moving to another package—or even finding references! I've already filed [eclipse-jdt Bug #154](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/154) and [eclipse-jdt Bug #115](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/115), but for now just to make progress I need to know how to work around these bugs. Here's an example:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.24.0.I20220607-0700
java.version=17.0.3
java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.jdt.ui
Error
Mon Jun 20 15:45:07 PDT 2022
Internal Error

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.lambda$7(WorkbenchWindow.java:2345)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2343)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper.perform(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper.perform(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.refactoring.RenameSupport.perform(RenameSupport.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.RenameLinkedMode.doRename(RenameLinkedMode.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.RenameLinkedMode$EditorSynchronizer.left(RenameLinkedMode.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeModel.exit(LinkedModeModel.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeUI.lambda$2(LinkedModeUI.java:1172)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4043)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3648)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedTypeReference.getTypeBinding(QualifiedTypeReference.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.accept(MatchLocator.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3466)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:3173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveTypeArgument(TypeReference.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.internalResolveLeafType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.internalResolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.resolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:2627)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:1550)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.internalFaultInTypeForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.faultInTypesForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.process(MatchLocator.java:2021)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.internalSearch(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.search(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameTypeProcessor.initializeReferences(RenameTypeProcessor.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameTypeProcessor.doCheckFinalConditions(RenameTypeProcessor.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.JavaRenameProcessor.checkFinalConditions(JavaRenameProcessor.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring.checkAllConditions(Refactoring.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper$Operation.run(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5929)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Root exception:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.QualifiedTypeReference.getTypeBinding(QualifiedTypeReference.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveSuperType(TypeReference.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.findSupertype(ClassScope.java:1670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectSuperclass(ClassScope.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ClassScope.connectTypeHierarchy(ClassScope.java:1454)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.connectTypeHierarchy(CompilationUnitScope.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(LookupEnvironment.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.accept(MatchLocator.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:276)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getTypeOrPackage(Scope.java:3466)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:3173)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.SingleTypeReference.getTypeBinding(SingleTypeReference.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.internalResolveType(TypeReference.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:625)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveTypeArgument(TypeReference.java:638)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.internalResolveLeafType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.internalResolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.resolveType(ParameterizedSingleTypeReference.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeReference.resolveType(TypeReference.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.resolveTypeFor(SourceTypeBinding.java:2627)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.fields(SourceTypeBinding.java:1550)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.internalFaultInTypeForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.SourceTypeBinding.faultInTypesForFieldsAndMethods(SourceTypeBinding.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.CompilationUnitScope.faultInTypes(CompilationUnitScope.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.process(MatchLocator.java:2021)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1353)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.MatchLocator.locateMatches(MatchLocator.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.JavaSearchParticipant.locateMatches(JavaSearchParticipant.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.findMatches(BasicSearchEngine.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.search(BasicSearchEngine.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.search(SearchEngine.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.internalSearch(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.RefactoringSearchEngine.search(RefactoringSearchEngine.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameTypeProcessor.initializeReferences(RenameTypeProcessor.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.RenameTypeProcessor.doCheckFinalConditions(RenameTypeProcessor.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.rename.JavaRenameProcessor.checkFinalConditions(JavaRenameProcessor.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.participants.ProcessorBasedRefactoring.checkFinalConditions(ProcessorBasedRefactoring.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.Refactoring.checkAllConditions(Refactoring.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.RefactoringExecutionHelper$Operation.run(RefactoringExecutionHelper.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5929)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.run(WorkbenchRunnableAdapter.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
```

Does anyone know of a workaround? I could go to the file system and spend an hour moving files and then searching for references, but if I do that I might as well use VS Code. It sort of defeats the purpose of an IDE, and it would steal so much of my time.

Is there some cache I can clear? Is there an index I can rebuild? This is such a huge, irritating roadblock to productivity.

Here's what I have installed:

```
  Axis2 Tools   1.1.401.v201909051708   org.eclipse.jst.ws.axis2tools.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle    3.1.6.v20220511-1359    org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship
  CXF Web Services  1.1.900.v202107101953   org.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Dali Java Persistence Tools - Common  1.5.100.v201903221940   org.eclipse.jpt.common.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink Common  1.3.200.v201903221940   org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JAXB Support    1.4.203.v202104080213   org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.eclipselink.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Dali Java Persistence Tools - EclipseLink JPA Support 3.4.101.v201903221940   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.eclipselink.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Dali Java Persistence Tools - JAXB Support    1.5.201.v202104080213   org.eclipse.jpt.jaxb.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Dali Java Persistence Tools - JPA Support 3.6.1.v202204060305 org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Connectivity  1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Connectivity Documentation    1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement    1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement Extender SDK   1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sdk.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for Apache Derby   1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.apache.derby.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for HSQLDB 1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.hsqldb.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for IBM    1.14.103.202103070014   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ibm.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for Ingres 1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.ingres.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for JDBC   1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdbc.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for Microsoft  1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.msft.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for MySQL  1.14.103.202107071900   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.mysql.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for ODA Designer   1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.designer.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for ODA Runtime    1.14.102.201911221603   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for Oracle 1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oracle.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for PostgreSQL 1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.postgresql.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for SAP MaxDB  1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sap.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for Sqlite 1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sqlite.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Enablement for Sybase 1.14.201.202107090755   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.sybase.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Extender SDK  1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.sdk.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Intro 1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.intro.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform JDT Enablement    1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdt.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Model Base    1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.modelbase.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Open Data Access Designer 1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Open Data Access Designer Core    1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.core.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Open Data Access Runtime  1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Dev Tools Documentation   1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.doc.user.feature.group   Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools 1.14.201.202107090755   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools Data Functions  1.14.201.202107090755   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.data.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools DDL Functionality   1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddl.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools DDL Generation Functionality    1.14.201.202107090755   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.ddlgen.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools Results View    1.14.201.202107061424   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.results.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Parsers   1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.parsers.feature.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Query Builder 1.14.201.202107090755   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.sqlbuilder.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform SQL Schema Object Editor Feature  1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.sqldevtools.schemaobjecteditor.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform Tutorial Documentation    1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.common.doc.user.feature.group Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  Data Tools Platform User Documentation    1.14.102.201911250848   org.eclipse.datatools.doc.user.feature.group    Eclipse Data Tools Platform
  EclEmma Java Code Coverage    3.1.6.202206011447  org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group   Eclipse EclEmma
  Eclipse Faceted Project Framework 3.7.3.v202111212041 org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Eclipse Faceted Project Framework JDT Enablement  3.24.0.v202111201707    org.eclipse.jst.common.fproj.enablement.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers    4.24.0.20220609-1200    epp.package.jee Eclipse Packaging Project
  Eclipse Java Development Tools    3.18.1200.v20220607-0700    org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools   3.26.0.v202204042240    org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools  3.26.0.v202204042240    org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment   3.14.1200.v20220607-0700    org.eclipse.pde.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Eclipse XSL Developer Tools   1.3.1100.v202204040421  org.eclipse.wst.xsl.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Git integration for Eclipse   6.2.0.202206071550-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group  Eclipse EGit
  Java implementation of Git    6.2.0.202206071550-r    org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group  Eclipse JGit
  JAX-WS DOM Tools  1.0.400.v202104210249   org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.dom.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JAX-WS Tools  1.2.800.v202104210249   org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JSF Tools 3.10.200.v202204070252  org.eclipse.jsf.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JSF Tools - Tag Library Metadata (Apache Trinidad)    2.6.1.v201902121810 org.eclipse.jst.jsf.apache.trinidad.tagsupport.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JSF Tools - Web Page Editor   2.9.1.v202111210733 org.eclipse.jst.webpageeditor.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JST Server Adapters   3.2.700.v202204301608   org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JST Server Adapters Extensions (Apache Tomcat)    3.4.400.v202204080102   org.eclipse.jst.server_adapters.ext.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JST Server UI 3.4.500.v202103180201   org.eclipse.jst.server_ui.feature.feature.group Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete   17.0.3.v20220515-1416   org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group    Eclipse JustJ
  M2E - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components)  1.20.1.20220227-1319    org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  M2E - PDE Integration 1.20.0.20220208-0831    org.eclipse.m2e.pde.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  M2E - POM Editor using LemMinX language server (includes Incubating components)   1.18.4.20220127-1634    org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  M2E - SLF4J over Logback Logging (optional)   1.17.2.20211002-1029    org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  m2e-wtp - JAX-RS configurator for WTP (Optional)  1.4.4.20201128-1705 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.feature.feature.group Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
  m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.4.4.20201128-1705 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
  m2e-wtp - JSF configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.4.4.20201128-1705 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
  m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP   1.4.4.20201128-1705 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e-wtp
  Marketplace Client    1.10.0.v20220502-0731   org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group   Eclipse Marketplace Client
  Mylyn WikiText    3.0.42.202201072301 org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Node.js embedder from Wild Web Developer  0.2.9.202205271506  org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.embedder.node.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Wild Web Developer project
  Oomph Setup   1.25.0.v20220607-1104   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group   Eclipse Oomph Project
  Tip of the Day UI Feature 0.2.1700.v20220220-0850 org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group  Eclipse.org
  TM Terminal   10.7.0.202204110055 org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group   Eclipse CDT
  Wild Web Developer HTML, CSS, JSON, Yaml, JavaScript, TypeScript, Node tools  0.10.14.202205271506    org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Wild Web Developer project
  WST Server Adapters   3.2.1000.v202204301608  org.eclipse.wst.server_adapters.feature.feature.group   Eclipse Web Tools Platform
```

Comment: Please post your eclipse build version and also your list of installed features with versions! Help >> About Eclipse Platform >> Installation Details >> Installed Software >> select all items and copy to clipboard. I use 2021-09 and have no problems with refactoring. The official releases should be properly tested and refactoring should not be a problem. Maybe some misfortunate plugin combination.

Comment: OK, I added my installed software. Though surely the error stack trace would indicate something no?

Comment: The exception you posted is caused directly by the JDT compiler plugin, which is quite strange.
Oh, by the way, don't get your hopes up about receiving support on those bug reports. In my opinion Eclipse has been on life support for quite a while, although I may be wrong on this.

Comment: That's sad because IntelliJ is horrendous to use. (I was just forced to use it for over a year.) It has a ton of its own things that break, and you can't even do simple things like double-click and select an entire word/token.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, on Linux x64 though. Can you try and extract the eclipse package in a new location and with a new workspace. Then create a java project and try to refactor. Does it show the error again?

Comment: Eclipse Release 4.24 shows some test failures on [jdt.core.tests.model](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.24-202206070700/testresults/html/org.eclipse.jdt.core.tests.model_ep424I-unit-win32-java11_win32.win32.x86_64_11.html) which seems to be relevant. Can you try if the error occurs with a lower release? Also you can backup your workspace and try to load it with a newer milestone version, for example I20220705-0600 from here: https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but I don't have days to waste doing this sort of shot-in-the-dark testing. This is the workspace I've been using (and upgrading with every release) for probably a decade or more. Everybody says, "oh, try a new milestone", which is just a time waster if there is no indication anything was fixed relevant to the problem. I'm sure a new test project would not show the issue; it likely has something to do with the particular combination of projects I have. But that is what a stack trace and unit tests are for.

Comment: This happened in 2022-03 as well. In fact I filed https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/115 against 2022-03. There I was told, "Would you please try 4.24 RC1?" even though there was no indication anything that was fixed related to this problem—just crossing of fingers and wishful thinking. Sure enough it's still there in 2022-06.

Comment: Incidentally, IDEA does select a word on double click, although placing the cursor and using repeated ctrl-W is often easier and more useful, as each ctrl-W increases the scope of the selection.

Comment: I don't know what else to say. From my experience dragging old workspaces with Eclipse leads to all kinds of persistent errors. Migrating data is quite risky. I always recreate my workspace and import the Maven projects from scratch when I install a new Eclipse. I know it's tedious, that's why I don't upgrade often. But for me chasing these kinds of upgrade errors has proven too costly and I prefer starting clean.

Comment: Except for these data migration inconsistencies and the troubles with some obsolete plugins that make version dependency troubles, I still use Eclipse and I think it's refactoring and other capabilities are superb. If you get used to the quirks, working can be very efficient indeed.

Comment: Are all of the classes you're working on in packages, and not using the "Default" package?

Comment: Yes indeed. I don't use the "default" package. Again this is a workspace with many, many projects. Renaming, moving, and finding references have always worked fine (in this same workspace!) for one or two decades. Until Eclipse EE 2022-03.

Comment: `InvocationTargetException`? Does running Eclipse with Java 11 instead of Java 17 fix your issue?

Comment: Running Eclipse with Java 11 instead of Java 17 does not fix the issue.